# How to extract weights from trained tensorflow object detection api model

Tags: object-detection-api

I am using the Tensorflow Object Detection API to train a couple of models (with SSD and Faster RCNN) in a custom dataset. Everything works well, but I want to know how to extract the convolutional and classification model weights, in order to load those weights in an external (for instance keras) convolutional and full connected corresponding model. I've read about the meta architectures (`SSDMetaArch` and `FasterRCNNMetaArch`) and restoring checkpoint, but I am not sure yet how to do it for my purpose.

The above because I want to use something like CAM or GradCAM to visually check what the model learns for every class in my dataset.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read weights saved in tensorflow checkpoint file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118062/how-to-read-weights-saved-in-tensorflow-checkpoint-file)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. No really because I need not only to load the checkpoint model (which is not a problem) but to use just a subset of the entire model, it is the feature extractor and the classification head. 

Currently I am able to get the detected bounding boxes with corresponding class and score for every object in image. Now I want to crop every detected bounding box (ROI) and feed it through only feature extractor and classification (this is what's needed for class activation maps)